# Alignment issue in Java Swing screen

Tags: java, swing, alignment

I am facing an alignment issue in Java Swing screen. I have borderLayout here. My requirement is based on different buttons click suitable query will be executed and populated in JTable. But this screen is having an alignment problem, and JTable is hiding all other components. Below is the code:

```
public class UI {
    static JTextField inputText = new JTextField(20);
    static JLabel errMsgLbl = new JLabel();

    static PreparedStatement ptsmt;
    static ResultSet rs;
    static JButton nameButton;
    static JButton accnoButton;
    static JButton countryButton;
    static JButton altaccButton;
    static JButton showAllButton;
    static JButton clearButton;
    static JButton exitButton;
    static JButton prevButton;
    static JButton nextButton;

    static JLabel searchBy;

    static String[] columnNames = { "ID", "Name", "Original Name",
            "Account Number", "Country", "Alternate Account No",
            "Related Party Name", "Select" };
    static JTable table;

    static JComponent createHorizontalSeparator() {
        JSeparator x = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        x.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 3));
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            DBConfig.loadEngineConfiguration();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JTable table = new JTable(50, 8);
        JPanel topPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel cntrPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel bottomPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel hdrPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel srchPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.LEADING));

        JPanel topBtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel bottombtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.LEADING));

        JPanel navbtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        JPanel tblPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
                FlowLayout.CENTER));

        hdrPnl.add(new JLabel("Welcome"));
        srchPnl.add(new JLabel("Input text"));
        srchPnl.add(inputText);

        topPnl.add(hdrPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPnl.add(srchPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        searchBy = new JLabel(DBConfig.searchBy);
        nameButton = new JButton(DBConfig.nameBtn);
        accnoButton = new JButton(DBConfig.accNoBtn);
        countryButton = new JButton(DBConfig.countryBtn);
        altaccButton = new JButton(DBConfig.altAccNoBtn);
        showAllButton = new JButton(DBConfig.showBtn);
        clearButton = new JButton(DBConfig.clearBtn);
        exitButton = new JButton(DBConfig.exitBtn);
        prevButton = new JButton(DBConfig.prevBtn);
        nextButton = new JButton(DBConfig.nextBtn);

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                inputText.setText(null);
                errMsgLbl.setText(null);
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Container frame = exitButton.getParent();
                do
                    frame = frame.getParent();
                while (!(frame instanceof JFrame));
                ((JFrame) frame).dispose();
            }
        });

        topBtnPnl.add(searchBy);
        topBtnPnl.add(nameButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(accnoButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(countryButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(altaccButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(showAllButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(clearButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(exitButton);

        //cntrPnl.add(topBtnPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //cntrPnl.add(bottombtnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cntrPnl.add(topBtnPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cntrPnl.add(bottombtnPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cntrPnl.add(createHorizontalSeparator(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        navbtnPnl.add(prevButton);
        navbtnPnl.add(nextButton);


        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tblPnl.add(table, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        bottomPnl.add(navbtnPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottomPnl.add(tblPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //table.setTableHeader(columnNames);

        frame.add(topPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(cntrPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bottomPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setTitle(DBConfig.appName);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: i ran this prog and got a normal output like textfield at top then buttons under that and then table under that

Comment: I know, but only text fields and couple of buttons are coming up with table, rest of the buttons and Horizonatal lines are missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
The BorderLayout supports only one component per region and you add navbtnPnl and tblPnl to the SOUTH region of bottomPnl, and tblPnl is the last one added which replaces the previously added navbtnPnl component.
```

Also you should not put your JTable directly in a JPanel if you want your table header to be displayed. You should add it to a JScrollPane instead which will display the header properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong layout. Use GridBagLayout. i tried it, Here is partial working example

```
public class UI
{
    static JTextField inputText = new JTextField(20);

    static JLabel errMsgLbl = new JLabel();

    static PreparedStatement ptsmt;

    static ResultSet rs;

    static JButton nameButton;

    static JButton accnoButton;

    static JButton countryButton;

    static JButton altaccButton;

    static JButton showAllButton;

    static JButton clearButton;

    static JButton exitButton;

    static JButton prevButton;

    static JButton nextButton;

    static JLabel searchBy;

    static String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Name", "Original Name", "Account Number", "Country", "Alternate Account No",
            "Related Party Name", "Select"};

    static JTable table;

    static JComponent createHorizontalSeparator()
    {
        JSeparator x = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        x.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 3));
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            // DBConfig.loadEngineConfiguration();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        final JTable table = new JTable(50, 8);
        JPanel topPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel cntrPnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));
        JPanel bottomPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel hdrPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel srchPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        JPanel topBtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel bottombtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        JPanel navbtnPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        JPanel tblPnl = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        hdrPnl.add(new JLabel("Welcome"));
        srchPnl.add(new JLabel("Input text"));
        srchPnl.add(inputText);

        topPnl.add(hdrPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPnl.add(srchPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        searchBy = new JLabel("searchBy");
        nameButton = new JButton("nameBtn");
        accnoButton = new JButton("accNoBtn");
        countryButton = new JButton("countryBtn");
        altaccButton = new JButton("altAccNoBtn");
        showAllButton = new JButton("showBtn");
        clearButton = new JButton("clearBtn");
        exitButton = new JButton("exitBtn");
        prevButton = new JButton("prevBtn");
        nextButton = new JButton("nextBtn");

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                inputText.setText(null);
                errMsgLbl.setText(null);
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Container frame = exitButton.getParent();
                do
                    frame = frame.getParent();
                while (!(frame instanceof JFrame));
                ((JFrame) frame).dispose();
            }
        });

        topBtnPnl.add(searchBy);
        topBtnPnl.add(nameButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(accnoButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(countryButton);
        topBtnPnl.add(altaccButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(showAllButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(clearButton);
        bottombtnPnl.add(exitButton);

        cntrPnl.add(topBtnPnl);
        cntrPnl.add(bottombtnPnl);
        cntrPnl.add(createHorizontalSeparator(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        navbtnPnl.add(prevButton);
        navbtnPnl.add(nextButton);

        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        cntrPnl.add(table, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        bottomPnl.add(navbtnPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottomPnl.add(tblPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//        table.setTableHeader(columnNames);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
//        c.weighty = 10;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(topPnl, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 40; // make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.2;
        c.weighty = 80;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(cntrPnl, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(bottomPnl, c);

        frame.setTitle("appName");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Previous and Next buttons are not showing up, also for center panel and bottom panel height is quiet big. Could you please help me in that as well?